# How to perform bitwise operations arithmetic in MS-ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, bitwise-operators

Inside MSACCESS I want to use relatively simple bitwise operations in `WHERE` clause of queries such as this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE Column1 (some operator) 8 = 0
```

This would:

- Return rows where `Column1` does not have its 4th bit set e.g. 0, 1, 2, ..., 7 (all have their 4th bit clear) and 16 (it is 00010000b)
- Exclude rows where `Column1` is 8, 9, 10, ..., 15 etc.

PS: are bitwise operators different from boolean operations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can run your query in in [ANSI-92 Query Mode](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/about-ansi-sql-query-mode-mdb-HP003070483.aspx?redir=0) (e.g. by changing the Access UI Query Mode or by connecting to it using ADO classic or ADO.NET), use the `BAND` operator.

The following code sample prints this to the Immediate window:

```
8 AND 7: -1 
8 BAND 7: 0
```

The first case (AND) treats both numbers as True values, so `True AND True` gives -1 (True).  I think the BAND approach is what you're after.

```
Public Sub BitwiseAndQuery()
    'the db engine treats numbers as booleans with AND '
    Debug.Print "8 AND 7: "; _
        CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT 8 AND 7")(0)

    'ADO includes BAND for bitwise AND '
    Dim rs As Object
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.Open "SELECT (8 BAND 7)", CurrentProject.Connection
    Debug.Print "8 BAND 7:"; rs(0)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check. Does the same apply when using ADO.NET?

Comment: I would guess yes.  But I don't do ADO.NET so my guess is about worthless.  :-)

Comment: The other bitwise operators as `BOR` and `BXOR`.

Comment: Yup, worked right away when I queried an MS-Access database through ADO.Net.

Answer (score 7):

you could:

```
WHERE (((column\(2^b)) mod 2) = 1)
```

edit: (where b is the specific bit to test)

OR is not available in Access unless you set ANSI Mode.

Comment: WHERE (int([column_name]/(2^[zero bit test]) mod 2 = 1)

Answer (score 1):

In VBA, you can apply the Boolean operators to numbers in order to perform bitwise operations

```
(13 AND 8) = 0
```

In SQL, however, this does not work. However, you could write a VBA function that you call inside a query.